# How to see before/after state of entities in SubSonic?

Tags: subsonic

I have a few large forms that I need to provide visual cues about the before/after state, so the person approving the form can see what has been modified (not the previous answer, tho that would be a plus).  This is currently being done with an extra column for each column of data (Name, Name_IsModified, Phone, Phone_IsModified, etc...).  I'm curious if there was a better way to getting around this, leveraging SubSonic?

The initial load is done by grabbing data from 6 source tables on 3 different servers.  This data is saved in the form tables, where it resides until it is approved by various people who will manually update it into the live systems that then update the 6 source tables.  The visual cues are primarily used during the approval process, but are occassionaly used to research when a change has been made in the past.

Since I have to make a bunch of updates, I thought this might be a good time to break away from the legacy 2000+ lines of code, making my job a bit easier!!!

Thanks,

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the properties on SubSonic objects are actually collections and you can pull this out and review changes - all without reflection.

We have a "DirtyColumns" collection (not sure if it's public or not) that we use to run updates - this would be the thing you'd want to have a look at.